Timeout exception with selenium and python. What is wrong with this navigation?
the idea of the code is simple. It will go to the search's page, "see" all the products there, click one by one, scrape all the data, go back to the search's page and click on the next product's link. So I'm doing something like this:
def extract_prodirectsports_data():
    url_line = "https://www.prodirectsport.com/soccer/l/adults/departments-boots/activity-football/brand-adidas/silo-predator/"
    sheet_data = []
    pdf_data = []
    sizes = []

    cotacao_libra()  # Assuming this function is already defined
    i = 0
    driver.get(url_line)
    
    #Cookies
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@title='Accept all cookies']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='zonos']")))
    close_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class = 'z-close']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close_button)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='global-popup']")))
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@aria-label='Close']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    #driver.implicitly_wait(500000)
    
    df_sheet = pd.DataFrame(columns=SHEET_COLUMNS)
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
    
    driver.maximize_window()

    product_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'product-listing__grid']//div[@class = '_root_129ai_6 product-listing__grid-item']/a"))
        )
    while True:
        
        for index, value in enumerate(product_list):
            product_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'product-listing__grid']//div[@class = '_root_129ai_6 product-listing__grid-item']/a"))
        )

            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", product_list[index])
            
            driver.save_screenshot("window.png")
            image_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "img")))
            image = image_element.get_attribute("src")
            i += 1
            
            actions.move_to_element(product_list[index]).perform()
            
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", product_list[index])
            driver.implicitly_wait(50)
            #driver.save_screenshot("screenproduct.png")
            product_name = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ml-meta__title").text
            print(product_name)
            price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ml-prices__price").text
            price = re.sub("£", "", price)
            product_price = float(price)
            print(product_price)

            product_code = driver.current_url.split('-')[-1]
            print(product_code)
            
            size_list = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'ml-size__sizes']")
            
            if size_list:
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", size_list)
                for size in size_list.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ml-size__size qa-size-item']"):
                    product_size = size.text
                    sizes.append(product_size)
                    if "-" in size.text:
                        product_size = size.text.split('-')[0] 
                        sizes.append(product_size)
                    elif "(" in size.text:
                        product_size = size.text.split('(')[0]
                        sizes.append(product_size)
            print(sizes)

            price_in_reais = calculate_price_in_reais(product_price)  # Function needs to be defined
            sale_price = calculate_sale_price(product_price)  # Function needs to be defined

            sheet_data.append({
                    'Photo': image,
                    'Code': product_code,
                    'Description': product_name,
                    'Purchase': price_in_reais,
                    'Sale': sale_price,
                    'Sizes': sizes
                        })
            pdf_data.append({
                    'Photo': image,
                    'Code': product_code,
                    'Description': product_name,
                    'Price': product_price
                        })

            for index, row in pd.DataFrame(pdf_data).iterrows():
                for data in row.values:
                    pdf.cell(1.6, 0.5, str(data))
                pdf.ln()
            
            driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
            
            print("exited")
            driver.implicitly_wait(5000)
            botao_vermais = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'product-listing__view-more']/button")        
            
        if botao_vermais:
             botao_vermais.click()
             driver.implicitly_wait(50)
            
        else:
             break
    pdf.output(url_linha + 'cátalogo.pdf')
    df_planilha = pd.DataFrame(data_planilha)
    df_planilha.to_excel(url_linha + "catálogo.xlsx")    
    driver.close()



sometimes it gets around 5 products and then in the last product it still prints "exited" but then it throws a timeout exception. More usually, it gets stuck on first or second product and then throw the timeout exception, also printing "exited" before throwing timeoutexception. So I guess the error is between the go back command and the beginning of the loop. Also, can someone give me the feedback if I'm doing right on automatic scroll?
Trying to avoid timeout exceptions and do some automatic scroll.

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example The code shown in your question is not runnable

ok, I've edited and made the url visible, so people can test it.

Some suggestion:
use

EC.visibility_of_element_located()

insted of:

EC.presence_of_element_located()


Some suggestions:

Ensure Elements are Fully Loaded

Try-Catch Blocks

Explicit Waits

Refresh Product List
while True:
try:
product_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-listing__grid']//div[@class='_root_129ai_6 product-listing__grid-item']/a"))
)
     for index, value in enumerate(product_list):
         try:
             product_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                 EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-listing__grid']//div[@class='_root_129ai_6 product-listing__grid-item']/a"))
             )

             driver.execute_script("arguments.scrollIntoView();", product_list[index])
             driver.execute_script("arguments.click();", product_list[index])
             WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ml-meta__title")))

             product_name = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ml-meta__title").text
             price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ml-prices__price").text
             price = re.sub("£", "", price)
             product_price = float(price)
             product_code = driver.current_url.split('-')[-1]

             size_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ml-size__size qa-size-item']")
             sizes = [size.text.split('-').split('(') for size in size_list]

             sheet_data.append({
                 'Photo': image,
                 'Code': product_code,
                 'Description': product_name,
                 'Purchase': calculate_price_in_reais(product_price),
                 'Sale': calculate_sale_price(product_price),
                 'Sizes': sizes
             })

             driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
             WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                 EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-listing__grid']//div[@class='_root_129ai_6 product-listing__grid-item']/a"))
             )
             print("exited")

         except TimeoutException:
             print(f"TimeoutException on product {index}. Retrying...")
             driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
             WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                 EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-listing__grid']//div[@class='_root_129ai_6 product-listing__grid-item']/a"))
             )
             continue

     try:
         botao_vermais = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
             EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-listing__view-more']/button"))
         )
         botao_vermais.click()
     except TimeoutException:
         break

 except TimeoutException:
     print("TimeoutException on product list. Exiting loop.")
     break




How did you test this answer?
